# Summation: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, parameter-estimation

How can I write the expression below in alternative way?

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$

Where:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = n\bar x $

Comment: Is there any reason to think you can write it in an alternative way?

Comment: I was thinking if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = n\bar x $ is valid then there maybe could exist a similar resolution to the squared expression :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar x + \bar x)^2 \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar x)^2 - 2 \bar x (x_i - \bar x) + \bar x^2 \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar x)^2 + N \bar x^2 \\
& = N(\sigma^2 + \bar x^2)
\end{align}
is one way to rewrite the sum of squares.